# How to rename all folders based on pattern in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working on a Windows 10 computer, and I have a large number of folders named according to the following pattern:

```
4972-127685 - Paul Smith 100256862- Jul 9, 2022 745 AM
11923-6124692 - Alex Sutton 104149263- Jun 28, 2022 1159 AM
13132-125394 - Brian Thomas 102193824- Jun 30, 2022 959 PM
```

I want to rename the folders using only the nine digits before the last hyphen:

```
100256862
104149263
102193824
```

I don't know PowerShell but my internet searches suggest that's the tool I need for this task. What I've learned so far is that I can open the parent folder where the folders to be renamed are and then click on `File > Open Windows PowerShell` to get the PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Have you considered using something like [PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) it has a Renamer utility.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for [the suggestion @Ramhound](https://superuser.com/questions/1754231/rename-all-folders-based-on-pattern-windows-10#comment2724161_1754231), PowerRename in PowerToys worked great. I'm not very good at using regular expressions, so I did it in three steps:

```
[\s\S]*\s-\s
.+?(?=\s)
-[\s\S]*
```

For each step, I just left `Replace with` blank. Under `Apply to`, I chose `Filename only` and I activated the `Include folders` icon.

Comment: Try this regex: `^\d+-\d+.+?(\d+).+$`

Comment: FYI: From the parent of the target folders, the **PowerShell** rename command would be: `Get-ChildItem -Directory | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^.+(\d{9}).+$' , '$1'}`, which, with aliases, can be shortened to: `gci -ad | ren -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^.+(\d{9}).+$' , '$1'}`

Comment: [@Reddy](https://superuser.com/users/855367/reddy-lutonadio): I copied and pasted your regex suggestion in PowerRename, but `Apply` stays inactive. I'll need to study the combination of expressions to see what the line means, but for now I just wanted to flag it seems I would need to do something else to get it to work.